# Pick photo from gallery android 13 using React native 0.63

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native 0.63.3 and I'm unable to upgrade to newer versions for certain constraints.

How can I access and select photos from the gallery on Android 13 or newer?

I've utilized the ['react-native-image-picker'](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker) library and request permission.

Below is the basic code snippet I've implemented but its not work

```
launchImageLibrary((options as any) as ImagePicker.ImageLibraryOptions, async (response) => {
     console.log(response)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add media permission? inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

or

Ask permission only if the Android version is less than `13`

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (Platform.OS == "android" && DeviceInfo.getApiLevelSync() >= 33) {
     // request permission
   }
   return () => {};
 }, []);
```